# Measured voltage on coil

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits, voltage, induction

I have a simple circuit of coil with [inductance L](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductance#Circuit_analysis) $$u_c(t)= -L\frac{di}{dt}$$ and AC source with output voltage $u_s$

[image: simple circuit]

What is actually measured by the voltmeter ($u_c$, $u_s$ or $u_s - u_c$)?

If you know that the induced voltage is opposite to the source voltage, how would you explain that the measured voltage is not equal 0.

Comment: what do you think? include in the question what you have thought so far and what exactly confuses you

Answer (score 0):

According to Kirchhoff law's, all voltages in the loop must sum up to 0, thus
$$
u_c = u_s = L\frac{\mathrm{d}i}{\mathrm{d}t}
$$

Interesting is what happens with current. After small math you get
$$
\int\mathrm{d}i = i(t) = \frac{1}{L}\int u_s \mathrm{d}t
$$
If source is a sinusoidal of amplitude V, then
$$
i(t) = -\frac{V}{\omega L}\cos{\omega t}
$$

But your devices will most probable measure RMS value, for details refer to wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square

Comment: Isn't KVL law for this circuit $u_c + u_s = 0$, so $u_s = - u_c$

Comment: $u_s$ is an active voltage source, so it adds to the circuit, and $u_c$ is a passive element - it "receives" voltages, so is with minus. For example, RLC circuit with two sources you would write
$$u_{s1} + u_{s2} - u_r - u_l - u_c = 0$$It is similar to vector adding, draw voltage drops vectors on each element and you will find it.

Comment: That depends on how you define $u_c$, right? Taking your answer $u_c = u_s = -L\frac{\mathrm{d}i}{\mathrm{d}t}$, we have $0 = u_s - u_c = u_s - (-L \frac{\mathrm{d}i}{\mathrm{d}t}) = u_s + L \frac{\mathrm{d}i}{\mathrm{d}t}$

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: I think you have it wrong, see http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/inductor/ac-inductors.html $u_s \sim \sin{\omega t}$ and $i \sim -\cos{\omega t}$

Comment: Yes, you are right, I used your formula from question without paying attention to it, which is wrong, because correct formula is $u_c(t) = L\frac{\mathrm{d}i}{\mathrm{d}t}$. After this, minus sign is correct. I corrected my solution.

Comment: I am sorry, but your answer does not answer my question.

Comment: I assumed it is clear, but to saying it explicitely, voltmeter measures $u_c$ which is equal to $u_s$, but device most probably measure RMS value, for sinusoidal source (you did not specify it) it is $V_{rms} = \frac{2V}{\pi}$.

Comment: Sorry, last value is wrong, it is average volume, not RMS, you need another integral, wikipedia tells you everything.

Comment: If you don't include polarity signs for showing which side of a device is higher by $u_s$ and $u_c$, then you can't write an unambiguous loop equation. You ALWAYS should designate + and - references for voltages.